# ExtJS setting menuDisabled dynamically in grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

Trying to remove column header menu containing sort dynamically.
Set `menuDisabled = false` on **afterrender** event in every column.

```
Ext.each(view.getColumns(), function (item) {
     item.menuDisabled = true;
     // item.sortable = false; //this works perfectly
});
```

If instead of `menuDisabled` I try to put `sortable` as false, that works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because on afterrender the menu is already created, and setting the property will not disable it to appear, you should try it on init, or instead like you already did disable the sorting of the column.

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Bruno . I have moved the function from `afterrender` event to `beforerender` and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @GrumpyTurtle please mark my answer as correct if the answer worked

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *menuDisabled* is a config taken into account at column rendering, and changing it after that worthless. But there is a tricky way for toggling the column menu that **will only work if the column was rendered with menuDisabled set to false**.

So if dive into the column class source code, we will see that in the *renderTpl* config there is the following piece of code:

```
'<tpl if="!menuDisabled">',
    '<div id="{id}-triggerEl" data-ref="triggerEl" role="presentation" unselectable="on" class="',
    Ext.baseCSSPrefix, 'column-header-trigger', '{childElCls}" style="{triggerStyle}"></div>',
'</tpl>',
```

It will render a div el that will toggle the menu. So by toggling the visibility of this div, you will toggle the *menuDisabled* "state".

```
column.triggerEl.show();
column.triggerEl.hide();
```

In your case, you can disable the menu showing for all columns like so:

```
Ext.each(view.getColumns(), function(item) {
    item.triggerEl.hide();
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1r2h.